# Perl script to connect oracle database

Tags: perl, oracle11g, dbi, dbd

I am new to Perl Programming and database connectivity. Can anyone please let me know step by step procedure to write Perl Script for Oracle Database connectivity.

My Perl Verion is:

> This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 (v5.22.0) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
>   Copyright 1987-2015, Larry Wall
>   Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
>   GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

I have tried the below:

```
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:Local","SYSTEM","SYSTEM") or die print ("could not connect! $DBI::errstr \n");
```

Since I don't know what is this "dbi:Oracle:Local" I could not able to connect to Database.

Can you please let me know what is dbi, Oracle, local. if it is Hostname and oracle database name, how can I find the same in my computer.

Do I need to set any ENV variable in Perl?  If so, where and what I need to set?

Comment: Sorry, this really is too broad a question to answer meaningfully. Have you considered hiring someone who isn't new to perl and database programming?

Comment: `print` is not required when you are using `die`. `die` itself display the message.

Answer (score 2):

`dbi:Oracle` lets `DBI` know which driver to use. If you're connecting to an Oracle database, you'll never change these.

`Local` is either an actual database name on the local system, or a name listed in `TNSNAMES.ORA`. Substitute the name of the local database you'd like to connect to.

The next two parameters are username and password.

If you're connecting remotely, or need to do something more elaborate, consult [the docs](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.74/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm#connect), or one of the many available [guides](http://www.perl.com/pub/1999/10/DBI.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Here i ll share my TNSNAMES.ORA file. Can you please tell me Database name,SID,Host name,

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

Answer (score 1):

```
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:Local","SYSTEM","SYSTEM");
```

"dbi" is a string,
"Oracle" is the driver type,
"local" is the database name,
First "SYSTEM" is the username and second one is password.

```
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:databaseName", 'username', 'passwd' ) or die($DBI::errstr, "\n");
```

First read the basic concept of [Simple Database access using Perl DBI and SQL](http://perlmaven.com/simple-database-access-using-perl-dbi-and-sql).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. But can you please tell me how do i can find my driver name and Database name.